# Weight Painting and Selecting Bones

Tags: weight-painting

I can't get a handle on weight painting. My understanding is that you should be able to set the influence each bone has on different parts of the mesh, but I can't seem to select individual bones for weight painting. I've read that you need to first enter Pose Mode, then select a bone, then switch to Weight Paint mode, but "Weight Painting" no longer appears in my menu options when I'm in Pose Mode.

[image]

Comment: In Object mode, select the armature then Shift-Click the Object. Then go into Weight Paint mode, Ctrl-Click the bone you want to weight paint and paint away.

Answer (score 1):

*Weight Paint* mode is a mode for objects, not armatures. You need to first select the armature in *Object* mode, then <kbd>Shift</kbd> select the object, switch to *Weight Paint* mode, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>left click</kbd> to select the bones you want, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>left click</kbd> to add a bone.